# NiFi MergeContent to add a header with a new line in csv file

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

I am using MergeContent to merge csv contents. Finally I need to add a header to the csv file. Here is my configuration:
[image]

As per suggestions to add new line https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Adding-newline-when-using-mergecontent-processor-to-combine/td-p/240863
I am using Demarcator as `${literal('&#10;'):unescapeXml()}`

If I don't use Header, then my csv file is coming fine. But once I add the header then first line of csv file comes after the header without adding a new line. Now, after adding the demarcator I am observing that some of lines is missing and also first line is merged with header.

My output with above properties:

```
Name,City,First Name,Last NameJohn,New York,John, Kim

MaryAn,London,Mary,Hopkins
```

My output without Header and Demarcator:
5 lines of output as expected.

```
John,New York,John, Kim
MaryAn,London,Mary,Hopkins
Robin,Chicago,Rob,Barb
Donny,NewYork,Don,Singh
Rikki,London,Rikki,Patel
```

How to add new line after header and not miss my data

Comment: You can just hit shift + enter to provide a new line in the attribute text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I couldn't find solution for adding header in MergeContent. I used ReplaceText with below config:

```
Search Value : (?s)(^.*$)
Replacement Value : Name,City,First Name,Last Name
Replacement Strategy: Prepend
Evaluation Mode:Entire text
Line-by-Line Evaluation Mode:All
```

Remaining config values were default values

Comment: I won't consider this as an optimal solution. Same functionality should have been achieved using MergeContent processor itself, as it already allows me to add the Header